# Python/Installing cvxpy package error - setup.py egg_info with error code 1

Tags: python-2.7, pip, cvxpy

I'm trying to install cvxpy on my Mac through pip and through PyCharm and I'm getting the following error: "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-azdpOA/CVXcanon/". Would anyone know what's that and how to fix this?

My python is 2.7
My pip is 8.1.2 
My PyCharm is 4.5.4
My OSX is 10.8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module `CVXcanon` is a dependency by the [official installation instructions](http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/install/index.html).

> We recommend using Anaconda rather than the Python that comes with the Mac and installing pip, nose, NumPy, SciPy, and CVXOPT through Anaconda (i.e., conda install pip nose numpy scipy cvxopt). But it is not necessary to have Anaconda to install CVXPY, and the instructions below assume you do not have Anaconda.

Install the command line tools `xcode-select --install` and then install the module with all dependencies `pip install cvxpy`. You can use the `Terminal` tab in PyCharm.